# Why content provider returns null values for phone number?

Tags: android

I want to read contact numbers from my android phone. I used content provider for that, but i am getting null values. Here is my code :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        String column[] = new String[]{People.NAME,People.NUMBER};
        Cursor cur = this.managedQuery(People.CONTENT_URI, column, null, null, null);
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            String name;
            String number;
            do
            {
                number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex((People.NUMBER)));
                str+="\n"+number;
            }
            while(cur.moveToNext());
            txt.setText(str);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, `People` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it now but one thing I would change is that you do not need to use

```
cur.getColumnIndex((People.NUMBER))
```

because you already know that the column is the second one in your projection (so index=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Cursor getContactCursor(Context context) {
    String[] projection = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
    return context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
}
```

and in onCreate()..

```
contactsCursor = getContactsCursor(this);
while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
     String name = contactsCursor.getString(0);
     String number = contactsCursor.getString(1);
}
```